# Getting "Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIImage *' to parameter of type 'CIImage * _Nonnull' with JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: jsqmessagesviewcontroller

JSQMessagesViewController 
Using Xcode 7.0 Beta 5, I'm getting a warning of an "Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIImage *' to parameter of type 'CIImage * _Nonnull' in the copyWithZone method of JSQPhotoMediaItem.

Here's the method:

```
- (instancetype)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
     {
       JSQPhotoMediaItem *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] initWithImage:self.image];
       copy.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = self.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing;
       return copy;
      }
```

The warning is for the first line initializing the JSQPhotoMediaItem, and the initWithImage shows that it expects a (UIImage *)

```
    - (instancetype)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image
      {
       self = [super init];
       if (self) {
       _image = [image copy];
      _cachedImageView = nil;
      }
      return self;
      }
```

It also reports that: "Passing argument to paramteter 'im' here" referencing CISampler.h, which indeed has an initWithImage(CIImage *) im[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

change

`JSQPhotoMediaItem *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] initWithImage:self.image];`

into

`JSQPhotoMediaItem *copy = [[JSQPhotoMediaItem allocWithZone:zone] initWithImage:self.image];`

will get rid of this warning.